# Ionic: Clear text field on page load

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i have a text field in my html page as below :

```
<ion-input type="text"   (input)="getid($event.target.value)" autofocus="true" id="get_ticket_id"></ion-input>
```

i want this text field to be sent to  blank/empty every time page loads/ user comes to the page by opening application or using back-button

how can i achieve that, i have done lot of search on this but could not find the solution, can someone please advise me how can it be acheieved

Comment: use life cycle hook `ionViewWillEnter()`

Comment: i tried life hooks but coming back to the page it still has the value there

Comment: I agree with @NajamUsSaqib, the best way to solve it, it's by using lifecycle hooks. But there're cases when they may doesn't work correctly in Ionic. Could you expose your routing structure for the component? P.S.: you always can track navigation between pages by using routing: `router.subscribe((val) => /*whatever*/)`.

Comment: @stackoverflowaccount can you share your `ionViewWillEnter()` code. Add it to your Question.

Comment: i don't know the code to be added in ionViewWillEnter() to clear the field, that's why posting the question.Could you please help with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ngModel`, that is one of absolute essentials you should learn about Angular. Also together with `ionViewWillEnter()` as suggested. So something like this:

ts:

```ts
myInput = "";

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.myInput = "";
}

getId(val) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

And the template:

```html
<ion-input [ngModel]="myInput" (ngModelChange)="getId($event)"></ion-input>
```

So I also suggest to use `ngModelChange` instead of `(input)`, we are coding with angular :)